# How to define more than one jenkins pipeline for a project?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My plan is this:

1. Let Jenkins build a project hosted in a git repo triggered by a new commit.
2. Then administrator will take a look at the build results. Base on the need of the project, the admin may want to tag the build.
3. Once the build is tagged, admin will push the tag into the git repo.

I have a simple pipeline to do step 1 ok. However, step 2 and 3 do not always happen to every jenkins build. I am not sure how to write a pipeline to fulfill my plan?

I would suppose that there is another jenkins pipeline other than the one doing the build to do step 2 and 3. Admin could run the second pipeline as he needs it. Or is there a way to code a logic to cover all the 3 steps in one pipeline? Admin selectively needs to manually input the git tag string when he wants a release build. However, according to pipeline doc, if an input is asked without getting user input, the pipeline is paused. In that to say the jenkins would leave a bunch of half-running pipelines if admin does not tag every build?

Comment: Why would you need a pipeline for that? Couldn't the admin just receive an email with the git hash, check that out, inspect the build and do "git tag <tag name>? What benefit are you trying to achieve with a second pipeline?

Comment: Small business.... for some none technical staff who doesn't know how to run git but ok to type string on website and click a button.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to use the [input step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/) combined with a [timeout](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#timeout-enforce-time-limit). When a git tag is entered as input, you set it, otherwise you go on as normal (after a short waiting period)